# Pipenv shell command creates new venv instead of loading existing

Tags: python, pipenv

I have been successfully using a virtual environment created by pipenv for months, located at ~/.virtualenvs. However, today when I tried to activate it using "pipenv shell" (while in the proper directory) pipenv creates a new .venv file in the current directory instead of loading the environment from ~/.virtualenvs. My main concern is: how do I redirect pipenv to the existing virtual environment? Out of curiosity, any ideas about what could suddenly cause this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just go to that project/venv bin folder and then do `source activate` it will as activate as it is just a wrapper around virtualenv

Comment: Thanks for this - it works. Why would pipenv suddenly start ignoring my outside-of-project venv?

Comment: this may [help](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/796)